# Trouble with matrix multiplication (java)

Tags: java, image-processing, matrix, matrix-multiplication, convolution

Im working with convolutional operations (feature map) and i have this issue:

when i input an square image the code runs perfectly and the output is the image transformed (everything ok with that)

this is the code:

```
   long ImageMatrix[][] = new long[width][height];
   int CounterColumns = 0;

BufferedImage KernelImg = new BufferedImage(width-2,height-2,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

  try {
        for (j = 0; j < height-2; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < width-2; k++) {
                for (w = 0; w < 3; w++) {
                    for (v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
                        int Sj = j + w;
                        int Sv = v + CounterColumns;
                        sum += ImageMatrix[Sj][Sv] * Kernel[w][v];
                    }
                }

                int a = 255;
                int p = (a << 24) | (sum << 16) | (sum << 8) | sum;
                sum = 0;
                CounterColumns++;
                count++;
                KernelImg.setRGB(j, k, p);
            }
            CounterColumns = 0;

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

the code above is the cycle that multiplies the kernel matrix (3x3 matrix) and the image matrix, this is an example of the kernel matrix:

```
int Kernel[][] = {

            {-1,-1,-1},
            {-1,8,-1},
            {-1,-1,-1}

    };
```

the problem is that when i input an rectangular image the system stop working and throw me this error:

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 165**

i already search for this error but i dont find anything that solve the problem and i dont know why the code runs with an square image with no problem but if i input an rectangular one the error shows up.

thanks if you can help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried running this through a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a asymmetrical: you deal with the columns differently than the rows; they both should be treated the same as far as indexes go:

```
try {
    for (j = 0; j < width-2; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < height-2; k++) {
            for (w = 0; w < 3; w++) {
                for (v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
                    int Sj = j + w;
                    int Sv = k+v;
                    sum += ImageMatrix[Sj][Sv] * Kernel[w][v];
                }
            }


    }
```

You also have to correctly use the indexes: j ranges in 0..width-2 and k in 0..height-2

Comment: **  sum += ImageMatrix[Sj][Sv] * Kernel[w][v];** in this line

Answer (score 0):

You have to center to kernel on the pixel you process. Here is a basic example for gray level images:

```
BufferedImage source = // A TYPE_BYTE_GRAY image
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY) ;

try {
    for (int y=1 ; y < height-1 ; y++)
        for (int x=0 ; x < width-1; x++)
            {
            int sum = 0 ;
            for (int i=-1 ; i <= 1 ; i++)
                for (int j=-1 ; j <= 1 ; j++)
                    sum += source.getRaster().getSample(x, y, 0) * Kernel[i+1][j+1] ;
            result.getRaster().setSample(x, y, 0, sum) ;
            }
    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace() ;
    }
```

In the case of gradients, the operation on borders is not well defined (different solution, but none is a good one), so in this example you end up with zeros.